# Javascript for "how many seconds have passed since this timestamp"

Tags: javascript

Is there a Javascript equivalent for this PHP code?

```
function secondsAgo($unixtime){
   return time() - $unixtime;
}
```

Example usage:

```
echo secondsAgo(time()-10); // 10
```

I have a unixtimestamp in Javascript and need to find out how many seconds have passed from today until that timestamp.

Comment: use Date.getTime() and divide by 1000 since it returns the count in milliseconds.

Comment: Personally I prefer `(new Date()).valueOf()` or `+new Date()` over `.getTime` which seems wrong to me. I feel like it should be _ms since midnight_ or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS equivelant:

```
function secondsAgo(unixTime) {
    return Math.round((new Date().getTime() / 1000)) - unixTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS timestamps are the same as Unix/PHP timestamps, time since Jan 1/1970, except JS uses milliseconds instead.

```
var msts = new Date().getTime(); // timestamps in millisecs;
var ts = msts / 1000; // now directly compariable to PHP timestamp.

var phpts = <?php echo json_encode(time()); ?>;

var diff = phpts - ts; // difference in seconds.
```